# Sum of a special infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Suppose that there exist constants $C$ and $\gamma\leqslant 3$ such that $\lambda_n \leqslant C n^{\gamma}$ for all $n$. Define a infinite series as follows: $$ \sum_{n \ge 1}\sum_{m \ge 1}\sum_{l \ge 1} \frac{1}{\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l}$$

So how to deduce that the series is divergent?

If you have some idea I would appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: You mean $\gamma \le 3$ right?

Comment: Yes, there is  a typo.

Comment: Edited everything in.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider, for a positive integer $k$, the set $S_k$ of all the triples $(n,m,l)$ of positive integers such that $\max\{n,m,l\}=k$. Then $|S_k|=k^3-(k-1)^3$ and $\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l\leqslant 3Ck^\gamma$ for $(n,m,l)\in S_k$. Therefore $$\sum_{n,m,l>0}\frac1{\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{(n,m,l)\in S_k}\frac1{\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l}\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^3-(k-1)^3}{3Ck^\gamma}=\infty$$ (by comparison with the harmonic series).

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! I could just offer another method to solving it. Notice that $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{l\ge 0}\frac{1}{\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l}\ge\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{l\ge m}\frac{1}{\lambda_n+\lambda_m+\lambda_l} \ge C \sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{l\ge 0}\frac{l}{n^{\gamma}+l^{\gamma}+l^{\gamma}} $$$$\ge C \sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{l\ge n}\frac{l}{n^{\gamma}+l^{\gamma}+l^{\gamma}}$$ then continue exchanging the order of the  two summations, you can make the summation lower.